# custom result after reviewing a stored procedures' result

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to return custom values as the values of the rows in case when no rows are fetched by executing the stored procedure

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `ROW_COUNT()` to test if any rows have been returned from a query. If the number of rows returned is zero, then you can run an alternative SQL statement to return your custom values:

```
--Execute your SQL statement
SELECT * FROM myTable

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 
BEGIN
     --SQL to return your custom values instead
     SELECT value1, value2, etc.
END
```

Comment: @abs: sorry, didn't realise you were using MySQL - try ROW_COUNT() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your own Select statement containing the values you want to return to the user. Something like this:

```
Select
   MyValue1,
   MyValue2,
   Myvalue3
```